# Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC)

Tags: linux, vnc

I have worked with my vnc remote on my vps linux centos 7. All of the sudden , the vnc service stopped. (I didnt change anything and firewall ports are ok) . I reboot the OS and nothing got changed.

This is my journal logs:

```
[root@static ~]# journalctl -xe | tail -30
Dec 02 04:00:48 MYHOSTNAME vmware-user.desktop[23432]: vmware-user: could not open /proc/fs/vmblock/dev
Dec 02 04:00:48 MYHOSTNAME gnome-session-binary[22922]: Entering running state
Dec 02 04:00:48 MYHOSTNAME tracker-store.desktop[23460]: (uint32 1,)
Dec 02 04:00:48 MYHOSTNAME libcanberra-login-sound.desktop[23434]: Failed to play sound: File or data not found
Dec 02 04:00:49 MYHOSTNAME vmware-user.desktop[23432]: Xlib:  extension "VMWARE_CTRL" missing on display ":4".
Dec 02 04:00:49 MYHOSTNAME gnome-shell[23107]: STACK_OP_ADD: window 0x1200001 already in stack
Dec 02 04:00:49 MYHOSTNAME gnome-shell[23107]: STACK_OP_ADD: window 0x1200001 already in stack
Dec 02 04:00:49 MYHOSTNAME gnome-shell[23107]: ActUserManager: user (null) has no username (object path: /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User0, uid: 0)
Dec 02 04:00:49 MYHOSTNAME gnome-shell[23107]: ActUserManager: user (null) has no username (object path: /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User0, uid: 0)
Dec 02 04:00:49 MYHOSTNAME gnome-shell[23107]: GNOME Shell started at Sat Dec 02 2017 04:00:46 GMT-0500 (EST)
Dec 02 04:01:01 MYHOSTNAME systemd[1]: Started Session 136 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-136.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-136.scope has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 02 04:01:01 MYHOSTNAME systemd[1]: Starting Session 136 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-136.scope has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-136.scope has begun starting up.
Dec 02 04:01:01 MYHOSTNAME CROND[23648]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 02 04:01:01 MYHOSTNAME run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[23652]: starting 0anacron
Dec 02 04:01:01 MYHOSTNAME run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[23659]: finished 0anacron
Dec 02 04:01:09 MYHOSTNAME dbus[668]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
Dec 02 04:01:09 MYHOSTNAME dbus-daemon[668]: dbus[668]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
Dec 02 04:01:09 MYHOSTNAME pulseaudio[23117]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME gnome-session-binary[22922]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME gnome-session[22922]: gnome-session-binary[22922]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME pulseaudio[23117]: [pulseaudio] module-x11-publish.c: PulseAudio information vanished from X11!
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-miner-f[23451]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-miner-fs.desktop[23451]: Received signal:15->'Terminated'
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-miner-f[23451]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME gnome-settings-[23319]: gnome-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server :4.
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME abrt-applet[23470]: abrt: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :4.
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-miner-f[23451]: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-miner-fs.desktop[23451]: OK
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-extract[23441]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-extract.desktop[23441]: Received signal:15->'Terminated'
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME gnome-shell[23107]: gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :4.
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-extract[23441]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-extract[23441]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-extract[23441]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-extract[23441]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-miner-user-guides.desktop[23459]: Received signal:15->'Terminated'
Dec 02 04:02:09 MYHOSTNAME tracker-miner-user-guides.desktop[23459]: OK
Dec 02 04:02:12 MYHOSTNAME systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
-- Subject: Unit vncserver@:4.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit vncserver@:4.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 02 04:02:12 MYHOSTNAME systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:4.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 04:02:12 MYHOSTNAME systemd[1]: vncserver@:4.service failed.
Dec 02 04:02:12 MYHOSTNAME polkitd[672]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22895:6151363 (system bus name :1.497, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

And this is my /var/logs

```
Dec  2 03:52:59 localhost systemd: Created slice User Slice of ahadvnc.
Dec  2 03:52:59 localhost systemd: Starting User Slice of ahadvnc.
Dec  2 03:52:59 localhost systemd: Started Session 132 of user ahadvnc.
Dec  2 03:52:59 localhost systemd-logind: New session 132 of user ahadvnc.
Dec  2 03:52:59 localhost systemd: Starting Session 132 of user ahadvnc.
Dec  2 03:53:00 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.problems' (using servicehelper)
Dec  2 03:53:00 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.problems' (using servicehelper)
Dec  2 03:53:00 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.problems'
Dec  2 03:53:00 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.problems'
Dec  2 03:53:00 localhost journal: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Dec  2 03:57:35 localhost systemd: Started Session 133 of user root.
Dec  2 03:57:35 localhost systemd-logind: New session 133 of user root.
Dec  2 03:57:35 localhost systemd: Starting Session 133 of user root.
Dec  2 03:57:35 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.problems' (using servicehelper)
Dec  2 03:57:35 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.problems' (using servicehelper)
Dec  2 03:57:35 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.problems'
Dec  2 03:57:35 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.problems'
Dec  2 03:57:36 localhost journal: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Dec  2 04:00:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 134 of user root.
Dec  2 04:00:01 localhost systemd: Starting Session 134 of user root.
Dec  2 04:00:39 localhost systemd: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
Dec  2 04:00:39 localhost vncserver: Killing Xvnc process ID 8662
Dec  2 04:00:39 localhost vncserver: Xvnc process ID 8662 already killed
Dec  2 04:00:42 localhost vncserver: New 'static..clients.your-server.de:4 (ahadvnc)' desktop is static..clients.your-server.de:4
Dec  2 04:00:42 localhost vncserver: Starting applications specified in /home/ahadvnc/.vnc/xstartup
Dec  2 04:00:42 localhost vncserver: Log file is /home/ahadvnc/.vnc/static..clients.your-server.de:4.log
Dec  2 04:00:42 localhost systemd: PID file /home/ahadvnc/.vnc/localhost.localdomain:4.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Dec  2 04:00:43 localhost gnome-session-binary[22922]: WARNING: Could not get session id for session. Check that logind is properly installed and pam_systemd is getting used at login.
Dec  2 04:00:43 localhost gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[22922]: WARNING: Could not get session id for session. Check that logind is properly installed and pam_systemd is getting used at login.
Dec  2 04:00:43 localhost gnome-session: generating cookie with syscall
Dec  2 04:00:43 localhost gnome-session: generating cookie with syscall
Dec  2 04:00:43 localhost gnome-session: generating cookie with syscall
Dec  2 04:00:43 localhost gnome-session: generating cookie with syscall
Dec  2 04:00:43 localhost gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop: GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/ahadvnc/.cache/keyring-HAMNAZ
Dec  2 04:00:43 localhost gnome-keyring-secrets.desktop: GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/ahadvnc/.cache/keyring-HAMNAZ
Dec  2 04:00:43 localhost gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop: GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/ahadvnc/.cache/keyring-HAMNAZ
Dec  2 04:00:43 localhost gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/ahadvnc/.cache/keyring-HAMNAZ/ssh
Dec  2 04:00:43 localhost pulseaudio[23117]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
Dec  2 04:00:44 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Dec  2 04:00:44 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Dec  2 04:00:44 localhost journal: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js 301]: octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated
Dec  2 04:00:44 localhost journal: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js 301]: octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated
Dec  2 04:00:44 localhost journal: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js 301]: octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated
Dec  2 04:00:44 localhost journal: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/gdm/loginDialog.js 1027]: anonymous function does not always return a value
Dec  2 04:00:44 localhost systemd: Started Session 135 of user root.
Dec  2 04:00:44 localhost systemd-logind: New session 135 of user root.
Dec  2 04:00:44 localhost systemd: Starting Session 135 of user root.
Dec  2 04:00:45 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.problems' (using servicehelper)
Dec  2 04:00:45 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.problems' (using servicehelper)
Dec  2 04:00:45 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.problems'
Dec  2 04:00:45 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.problems'
Dec  2 04:00:45 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service'
Dec  2 04:00:45 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service'
Dec  2 04:00:45 localhost systemd: Starting Location Lookup Service...
Dec  2 04:00:45 localhost journal: JS LOG: Failed to register AuthenticationAgent
Dec  2 04:00:45 localhost journal: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Dec  2 04:00:45 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
Dec  2 04:00:45 localhost systemd: Started Location Lookup Service.
Dec  2 04:00:45 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
Dec  2 04:00:46 localhost spice-vdagent[23317]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
Dec  2 04:00:46 localhost gnome-session-binary[22922]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
Dec  2 04:00:46 localhost gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[22922]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
Dec  2 04:00:46 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Dec  2 04:00:46 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Dec  2 04:00:46 localhost systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost systemd: Started Hostname Service.
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost journal: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js 367]: octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost journal: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js 367]: octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost journal: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js 367]: octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost journal: Unable to inhibit keypresses: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Permission denied
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service'
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost journal: g_task_return_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service'
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost systemd: Starting Locale Service...
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
Dec  2 04:00:47 localhost systemd: Started Locale Service.
Dec  2 04:00:48 localhost sealertauto.desktop: SELinux Troubleshooter: Applet requires SELinux be enabled to run.
Dec  2 04:00:48 localhost vmware-user.desktop: vmware-user: could not open /proc/fs/vmblock/dev
Dec  2 04:00:48 localhost gnome-session-binary: Entering running state
Dec  2 04:00:48 localhost tracker-store.desktop: (uint32 1,)
Dec  2 04:00:48 localhost libcanberra-login-sound.desktop: Failed to play sound: File or data not found
Dec  2 04:00:49 localhost vmware-user.desktop: Xlib:  extension "VMWARE_CTRL" missing on display ":4".
Dec  2 04:00:49 localhost journal: STACK_OP_ADD: window 0x1200001 already in stack
Dec  2 04:00:49 localhost journal: STACK_OP_ADD: window 0x1200001 already in stack
Dec  2 04:00:49 localhost journal: ActUserManager: user (null) has no username (object path: /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User0, uid: 0)
Dec  2 04:00:49 localhost journal: ActUserManager: user (null) has no username (object path: /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User0, uid: 0)
Dec  2 04:00:49 localhost gnome-shell: GNOME Shell started at Sat Dec 02 2017 04:00:46 GMT-0500 (EST)
Dec  2 04:01:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 136 of user root.
Dec  2 04:01:01 localhost systemd: Starting Session 136 of user root.
Dec  2 04:01:09 localhost dbus[668]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
Dec  2 04:01:09 localhost dbus-daemon: dbus[668]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
Dec  2 04:01:09 localhost pulseaudio[23117]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost systemd: vncserver@:4.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost gnome-session-binary[22922]: WARNING: Application 'nautilus-classic.desktop' killed by signal 15
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[22922]: WARNING: Application 'nautilus-classic.desktop' killed by signal 15
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost tracker-miner-apps.desktop: Received signal:15->'Terminated'
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost tracker-miner-apps.desktop: OK
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost gnome-session-binary[22922]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[22922]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost pulseaudio[23117]: [pulseaudio] module-x11-publish.c: PulseAudio information vanished from X11!
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost journal: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost tracker-miner-fs.desktop: Received signal:15->'Terminated'
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost journal: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost journal: gnome-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server :4.
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost journal: abrt: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :4.
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost journal: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost tracker-miner-fs.desktop: OK
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost journal: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost tracker-extract.desktop: Received signal:15->'Terminated'
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost journal: gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :4.
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost journal: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost journal: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost journal: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost journal: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost tracker-miner-user-guides.desktop: Received signal:15->'Terminated'
Dec  2 04:02:09 localhost tracker-miner-user-guides.desktop: OK
Dec  2 04:02:12 localhost systemd: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
Dec  2 04:02:12 localhost systemd: Unit vncserver@:4.service entered failed state.
```

Comment: Add the output of `systemctl status vncserver@:4.service`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. 
I set the geometry resolution in the service start . I removed it and the service started successfully